# IE8 Windows 7 Group Policy

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, group-policy

Currently when a user logs into a machine it opens IE8 to our intranet home page. I was wondering how/if I could set it to have two tabs open. The first one to our intranet home page and the second to a separate page.

Comment: Are you the network admin?

Comment: (this is superuser)

Answer (score 1):

User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Disable changing home page settings > Homepage 1

User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Disable changing secondary home page settings > Homepage 2

**Make sure these are not applied/active**  see [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverGP/thread/eb1c3fc7-cd91-4cf5-83f4-c3aa26a5ad75) for more information.